# What is log4j warning

Tags: java, swing, hibernate, log4j

I am using hibernate and java. When ever I try to load the form what i done with java the following warning appears.What is the following warning?

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

What is the need of log4j ? Why should I use this file? Even if I am not using log4j my program is running smoothly. Can any one tell me what is the purpose of log4j and what will happen if I am not creating this file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate uses Apache `Log4j` to log, which is very helpful to debug.

And `Log4j` by default looks for a file called `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` on the classpath. This is the message that you miss one of these two.

You can try one of the following solution:

1. Please create named `log4j.properties` and be in your classpath.
2. Create the log4j configuration files and when running your application, add:

   ```
   -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///path/to/your/log4j.properties
   ```

You may try adding these to the log4j.properties and see the results:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,console
####################Console logs######################
##log4j.appender.console= org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
##log4j.appender.console.encoding=utf-8 
##log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout
```

See more at:

- [Log4j introdutions](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)
- [How to configure Log4j in Hibernate project](http://developer.am/documentation/hibernate/?page=configure_log4j_hibernate_project)

Comment: But my doubt is what is the purpose of log4j and what will happen if I am not creating this file.

Comment: @AkshaiKumar for love of God you can google and research

Comment: @AkshaiKumar , this is a logging library hibernate uses. You may miss some logging information or facility without this configuration file.

Comment: @Akshai Kumar, it is used to log messages which are useful for debugging. Refer to this link - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j

Comment: @Jaskey plz add some info to your answer so the op can be happier

Comment: @Jaskey For clarification, Hibernate uses JBoss Logging in its latest version. Previously it was using SLF4J and before that, Commons Logging.